# How to add a meta box for categories in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add two meta boxes for categories, so that I can add additional content or information to each of my categories.

In the template of the categories I will then read the contents of those meta boxes, but how can I add meta boxes to categories? I can only see documentation for doing this on pages and posts or custom post types, but categories?

Comment: Hi, i was googled and found pretty good tutorial. I think this could help you https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/#toc-add

Comment: Removed tags from title